# How to Return a Query Result Even When Nothing Comes Up for the Results

Tags: sql, oracle, count, null

I have a table called "orders" with the following data:

```
   Date     Order_No     Ship_Method
-------------------------------------
12/6/2013   1234567       RTS
12/6/2013   7654321       
12/7/2013   3456789       RTS
12/7/2013   9876543       
12/7/2013   1123456       RTS
12/7/2013   5523847       RTS
12/8/2013   8876549    
12/8/2013   7733654
```

I need a query that will search for how many rows of data have "RTS" in the Ship_Method field and return the following result for the day I run the query (like below):

```
   Date     RTS_Shipments
-------------------------
12/8/2013         0
```

-Anthony C.

EDIT

The query that works for me concerning the above issue is the following (provded by Carth in the answers section):

```
select 
sub.tdate,
count(orders.dt)
from (select to_date(to_char((sysdate-1),'mmddYYYY'),'mmddYYYY') tdate from dual) sub
left join orders on sub.tdate = orders.dt and orders.ship_method like '%RTS%'
group by sub.tdate
```

Comment: On SQLFiddle, I was trying to do something like this:

`SELECT CASE WHEN to_char(dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY') IS NULL THEN
trunc(sysdate) ELSE to_char(dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY') END,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(ship_method) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(ship_method) END
FROM orders
WHERE trunc(dt) = trunc(SYSDATE - 1) AND ship_method Like '%RTS%'
GROUP BY trunc(dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY');`

But kept on getting this error message:

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got CHAR : SELECT CASE WHEN to_char...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the result you need here you will be required to create a basis for your select in which the term you're filtering on definitively exists and then use that to join to your target table. In my initial answer I was thinking that you could select a variable value directly from dual but since I can't get the syntax of that to work out correctly here are a couple of other ideas. You could create a new "working" table that has all the dates you want to check and then select against that and left join to your target table, or you could create a subselect to hold your intended value and use that as the basis of your statement like this:

```
select 
  sub.tdate,
  count(orders.dt)
from (select to_date(to_char((sysdate-1),'mmddYYYY'),'mmddYYYY') tdate from dual) sub
left join orders on sub.tdate = orders.dt and orders.ship_method like '%RTS%'
group by sub.tdate
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, @Carth.

This code does not work. When I run it in SQL Developer, I get the message below:

ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 7

Comment: @aCarella - I've updated the answer with a working example. I hope this helps.

Comment: This actually almost works. Awesome. Thanks for the help so far.

I ran it in sqlfiddle and it does in fact bring up a zero and a date in the columns that I need it to.

I was messing around with it, though, and I could not figure out how to automate it so that instead of '120913', the code will automatically check today's date. Any idea on how to do this for the day of the query?

Comment: @aCarella Just replace to_date('120913','mmddYY') with SYSDATE

Comment: If I wanted this to search for yesterday, wouldn't I type SYSDATE - 1? When I type SYSDATE the result I get is 0, which is correct because there are no entries for 12/9. But when I type SYSDATE - 1 (or 2 or 3) I am still getting a zero.

Also, I don't see anywhere in the code that searches for "RTS" in the ship_method column. This query is the closest I've come to solving this problem, but I still need it to search for the number of "RTS" strings in a given day should there be any.

Comment: @aCarella That's because you need to strip off the time part of the date. The updated example shows how to filter in the join condition and strip the time part from the date value

Comment: WOW! This works! Thank you so so much! This is exactly what I needed, and I've learned a lot going through all of the code that you and @JorgeCampos have provded. Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42787/discussion-between-carth-and-acarella)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a left join on the same table to get all results and the results that you need. The one that you need you sum 1 and 0 for the one you don't.

That should do.

```
 SELECT to_char(o1.DT, 'MM/DD/YYYY') As "Date", 
        SUM(case when o1.Ship_Method is null then 0 else 1 end) As RTS_Shipments
  FROM orders o1 
     left join orders o2 
        on (o1.dt = o2.dt and o2.Ship_Method like '%RTS%')
 WHERE trunc(o1.DT) = trunc(SYSDATE) 
 GROUP BY to_char(o1.DT, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

See it at fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fd374/6

I've changed the date field to dt because date is a reserved word.

And also. This query can count every date but it will show just the registries for the day you filter: `trunc(o1.DT) = trunc(SYSDATE)` if you take out this condition you will see every date with the proper count.

Comment: The OP needs a row returned even when nothing matches the where clause.

Comment: Considering the OP's comment "The problem arises when there are no RTS shipments for a particular day" what happens in your example if the select is for 12/9 instead of 12/8. Or conversely if you leave the select looking for SYSDATE but change the schema to move the records from 12/8 to 12/9?

Comment: @Carth since there is no data on the 12/9 **and** there is a filter on sysdate. There is no way to print the row with the 12/9 date unless the op create a table with all dates and do a left join with his table filtering it with the 12/9.

Comment: I really appreciate the comments so far.

None of the code in the comments section for this question has worked. I have tried it in the SQL Developer that I work with and it has not worked.

I have also tried it in the sqlfiddle.com link that you sent, @Jorge Campos, and it also does not work in that if you try another date (SYSDATE - 1 or -2, for example) it gives really off numbers like 9 (there aren't even 9 RTS strings in the example given).

I will keep digging and if I find the answer I will post it up. If anyone can figure this out, please post up a response. Much apprecaited.

-Anthony

Comment: @aCarella Then i think that your problem was not well explained. What about you put a sample data of your table and from that sample data you put the desired result it will be easier to give you a solution.

Comment: The sample data would be the first table that I posted (orders).

The desired result is that I want a column for the date, and another column with the number of RTS strings in ship_method for a given day. If there were no RTS strings in the ship_method column for the day, I want the column that counts the number of RTS strings to say "0".

I will make another post in the original post so I can better display what I want, @JorgeCampos.